# Vertical li content does not align in center

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to center vertical aligned menu items (Img and text) in a li.

Here is a screenshot how it is looking atm. Menu items are supposed to be centered.
https://i.gyazo.com/aaabc2d1f1ee8f75e12e044e8b0560a5.png

First to align the Image and the capture vertically I used

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

I also tried:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Both are aligning it vertically but the content is not centered. Any idea how to center it?

```css
.mx-navigationtree {
    background-color: $navigation-bg;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.navbar-inner>ul >li >a {
    color: black; //$navigation-color;
    background-color: white; //$navigation-bg;
    font-weight: bold; //$font-weight-normal;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}   

.navbar-inner>ul >li >a img {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-navigationtree">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="mx-name-2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-0 dropdown" data-item-id="2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-0"><img src="http://localhost:8080/img/img$briefcase_small_blue.png?636779626789785643"> List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mx-name-2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-1 dropdown" data-item-id="2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-1"><img src="http://localhost:8080/img/img$briefcase_small_blue.png?636779626789785643"> Card</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mx-name-2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-2 dropdown" data-item-id="2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-2"><img src="http://localhost:8080/img/img$briefcase_small_blue.png?636779626789785643"> Chart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your expected screen?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/aaabc2d1f1ee8f75e12e044e8b0560a5.png 
looks like this atm. The Menu items are supposed to be centered.

Comment: `text-align:center`?

Comment: simply you can add `<br/>` as I have seen the required screen.

Comment: @Pete not working, tried that already.

Comment: Make sure your divs and the ul are 100% width of that side bar - I see you made it inline block which probably means it does not take the full width - which is why it is not horizontally centring

Comment: Your content _is_ centered - you just don’t notice it, because the element you are centering it in is only as big as the content inside it demands it in the first place. You only made your `a` elements `display:table-cell` here - you did not give them a width or height, and since non of the elements on the upper levels have been assigned table properties as well, there is not even a connection between the different `a` elements here (like that the one with the longest text would give the width for the other “table” columns would follow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not alwasy necessary to use display:table-cell and vertical align middle.

Have a look on alternative solution.

```css
.mx-navigationtree {
    background-color: $navigation-bg;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width:100%;
}

.navbar-inner>ul >li{
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;
}
.navbar-inner>ul >li >a {
    color: black; //$navigation-color;
    background-color: white; //$navigation-bg;
    font-weight: bold; //$font-weight-normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}   

.navbar-inner>ul >li >a img {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-navigationtree">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="mx-name-2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-0 dropdown" data-item-id="2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-0"><img src="http://localhost:8080/img/img$briefcase_small_blue.png?636779626789785643"> List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mx-name-2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-1 dropdown" data-item-id="2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-1"><img src="http://localhost:8080/img/img$briefcase_small_blue.png?636779626789785643"> Card</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mx-name-2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-2 dropdown" data-item-id="2f63aabf-9ade-4aac-96d7-768044c6b569-2"><img src="http://localhost:8080/img/img$briefcase_small_blue.png?636779626789785643"> Chart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```